# Array List action listener

Tags: java, android

Hello I was trying to add action listener to array of string so 
Is it possible to add `onclicklistener` to an ArrayList of Strings? If possible can you tell me how please. 
Thank you

Comment: I added the onItemClickListener to ListView How can I get data from the clicked view in the list ?! I mean each item of the list view has 2 text views can I get the text of the current element's views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ListView has more than one TextViews use something like this to retrieve the data

```
    list.setOnItemClickedListener(new OnItemClickedListener() {
AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
    Textview i1 = view.findViewById(R.id.t1);
    Textview i2 = view.findViewById(R.id.t2);
    String text = i1.getText()+i2.getText();
    }
} ;
```

Comment: This one helped me thx .

Comment: Please mark up the answers if they are helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is a part of collection framework and is present in java.util package.

OnClickListener needs a View interface to be called upon.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are wanting to do but nor Strings nor ArrayLists have any method to handle an istance of OnClickListener.

The OnClickListener interfaces is meant to be used by Views.